# How to retrieve sumbitted data in modal

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I want in add content have a link(or button) when user click on lt the popup (modal or any popuping method like dialog,modal,lightbox,colorbox ) will open, in that form I want have some field, like hierarchical select and long text fields, after user submit that form, the submitted values passed back to add content form,

**appreciate any idea**

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest an approach which is not a solid, but you can get an idea;

- Create modal with Ctools (may be [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109163/how-to-use-ctools-modal-to-popup-some-fields-of-a-node-on-node-view/109186#109186) and [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108651/node-add-save-in-ctools-modal-fails/108687#108687) links can
  help you to create it);
- On form submission store the submitted data as array into $_SESSION;
- reload the page with `ctools_ajax_command_reload();`

example:

```
// This is must be in ctools modal callback. Read modal.html file in ctools/help directory
if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_reload();
}
```

- Alter the content add form;
- add `#default_value` to the fields, e.g.: `'#default_value' => isset($_SESSION['modal_data']['field_1_value']) ? $_SESSION['modal_data']['field_1_value'] : ''`;
- at the end of the content add form just unset the $_SESSION data, e.g.: `unset($_SESSION['modal_data'])`;

Comment: good idea, but I dont know how can I reload main page after modal form submit?

Comment: @zhilevan I updated the answer.